# How to debug updating an instance variable of a php Trait without using setters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

## Background

I'm trying to use the leeway property of [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) as recommended [here](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/887#issuecomment-435913387) to circumvent weird timezone differences.

The code in jwt is pretty straight forward, A [DateTimeTrait](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/develop/src/Claims/DatetimeTrait.php) trait is [used](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/develop/src/Claims/DatetimeTrait.php#L19-L26), at first with an instance variable called leeway:

```
trait DatetimeTrait
{
    /**
     * Time leeway in seconds.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $leeway = 0;
```

later on this helper method [is used](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/develop/src/Claims/DatetimeTrait.php#L62-L72) to determine if a given timestamp is in the future:

```
/**
 * Determine whether the value is in the future.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function isFuture($value)
{
    return Utils::isFuture($value, $this->leeway);
}
```

I was going over the code, and I realized that the value of leeway changes randomly. At some point I figured we're calling different trait classes so i used the [spl_object_hash](http://spl_object_hash) to know if we're using the same object, it turns out we do:

```
public function setLeeway($leeway)
{
    $this->leeway = $leeway;
    var_dump("set leeway: ".$this->leeway." on object: ".spl_object_hash($this));

    return $this;
}


protected function isFuture($value)
{
    var_dump("calling is future with leeway :".$this->leeway. " on object: ".spl_object_hash($this));
    return Utils::isFuture($value, $this->leeway);
}
```

but see the logs:

```
 string(60) "set leeway: 5000 on object: <obj-hash-1>"
 /vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Claims/DatetimeTrait.php:97:
 string(60) "set leeway: 5000 on object: <obj-hash-2>"
 /vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Claims/DatetimeTrait.php:71:
 string(76) "calling is future with leeway :0 on object: <obj-hash-1>"
```

where:

- `<obj-hash-1>` is `000000007386f4100000000038d49b05`
- `<obj-hash-2>` is `000000007386f4160000000038d49b05`

## Question

How it possible for the same trait to sometimes have the same instance variable 0, and then 500, without that instance variable being updated using a setter? How can I at least debug that property being updated (if it's not done through a setter)

Answer (score 0):

More debugging can be found [here](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/887#issuecomment-524572756). But after digging so deep into authentication, I figured I'd just follow Sun Tzu's unit testing [advice](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sun_Tzu): *it's best to win without fighting*.

So I mocked the whole authentication like so

```
public function getFakeClient()
{
    $data['type'] = 'client';
    $client = factory(App\User::class)->create($data);

    $this->be($client);

    $this->client = $client;

    Auth::shouldReceive('user')->andReturn($this->client);
    Auth::shouldReceive('check')->andReturn(true);

    return $this->client;
}
```

and before each scenario (I'm using Behat) I just skipped the auth middlewares:

```
public function beforeScenario(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->withoutMiddleware([\App\Http\Middleware\TokenAuthentication::class,
                              \App\Http\Middleware\TokenAuthorization::class
                             ]);
}
```